# Add Content in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to search through multiple files and underneath specific lines i need to insert lines referenced previously in each respective file.  So far i cannot get my script to work at all. 
This is what i have so far :

```
$TextLocation = "M:\test"
$files = get-childitem -filter *.gto -path $TextLocation

Foreach ($file in $files) {
  $pagetitle = "DS_PGSEQ-DC:"
  $a = Get-Content $file.FullName | Select-String "AssignedToUserID-TZ"
  $b = Get-Content $file.FullName | Select-String "EFormID-TZ"
  Foreach ($line in $file)
  {
    if([String]$line -eq "DS_PGSEQ-DC:0001")
    {
    }
    elseif([String]$line -eq $pagetitle) 
    {
      Add-Content $file.FullName ($a -and $b)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have example input and output to show?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by Input/Output?

Comment: He means give an example of some of the contents of one or more of these files you are trying to process.

Comment: DS_PGSEQ-DC:0002 (the number marks the page within each GTO file)         I have to add the selected string above below each page

Comment: If you cannot resolve a problem, you usually come up with a reduced test case, for which you have minimum input data and still able to reproduce the same issue. If you provided sample input, we'd able to better understand your concern.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways for inserting text into a text file:

1. Process the input file(s) line-by-line, write the output to a temporary file and replace the input file(s) with them temp file afterwards.

   ```
   for ($file in $files) {
     $filename = $file.FullName
     Get-Content $filename | % {
       if ( $_ -match 'seach pattern' ) {
         $_
         "new line"
       }
     } | Out-File $tempfile
     MoveItem $tempfile $filename -Force
   }
   ```
2. Read the entire content of the file(s), insert the text by using a regular expression replacement, and write the modified content back to the file(s).

   ```
   for ($file in $files) {
     $text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName)
     $text -replace '.*search pattern.*', "`$0`nnew line" |
       Out-File $file.FullName
   }
   ```

Comment: The problem in replace is that for each file what follows "AssignedToUserID-TZ" and "EFormID-TZ" is different but i need to copy that whole line.  I need a script that will grab those lines only knowing the beginning of the line and then insert them underneath the page line.  Replace would work only if i was copying the same exact lines over and over again

Comment: Behold the power that is regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$TextLocation = "M:\test"
$Outputlocation = "M:\test\output"
$files = get-childitem -filter *.gto -path $TextLocation

Foreach ($file in $files) {
  $pattern = "\d\d\d[2-9]"
  $found=$false
  $contains=$false

  $lines = Get-Content($file.FullName) |
    Foreach-object { 
      if ($_ -match "AssignedToUserID-TZ") {
        $a = $_
      }

      if ($_ -match "EFormID-TZ") {
        $b = $_ 
      }        

      if ($_ -match "DS_PGSEQ-DC:$pattern") {
        if($found -eq $false) {
          $found=$true
        }
      } else {
        $found=$false
      }

      if ($found -eq $true) {
        $contains=$true

        #Add Lines after the selected pattern
        $_
        $a
        $b
      }

      if ($found -ne $true) {
        $_
      }

    } | Set-Content($Outputlocation + "\" + $file.Name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone but this ended being what i needed

Comment: `$contains` is never used, and the last two conditionals can be simplified to `$_; if ($found) { $a; $b }`.